# Random warning popping up occasionally when using eshell

Tags: debugging, tramp, eshell, variables

I occasionally get this warning while running `eshell`:

```
Warning (comp): tramp-loaddefs.el.gz:745:2478: Warning: reference to free variable ‘tramp-remote-path’
```

and was wondering how to fix it. According to the docs, in most cases, it is not necessary for `tramp-remote-path` to be set, and I am actually not using `tramp` when this error occurs, so I am wondering what's going on and perhaps how I can investigate.

For more information, I built emacs from source on Saturday using native-comp and --without-pop flags.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: reported as bug#63102 (probably by OP)

Comment: Fixed in one of latest commit @shynur